# Need 12 hour format without showing AM/PM Timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [Timepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) from Angular directive for bootstrap.

I need to have 12 hour format only but without AM/PM

There is the plunkr link on the site that you can play around with.

I tried the option `$scope.ismeridian = false;` 
It let the am/pm hidden but the time count goes to 24 still.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a class to your timepicker:

```
<timepicker class="timepicker" ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
```

And then use CSS to hide the AM/PM button:

```
.timepicker tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I know, but I had a look at the source code and there's nothing you can do there. You can also create a directive that removes the button from the timepicker directive, but hiding it with CSS gets the job done.

Comment: You are right! Also need to show in 12 hour format in <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'HH:mm' }}</pre> Currently it show 15:45 let say.

Answer (score 1):

On the plunker link try to change this  line:

```
<pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
```

to this:

```
<pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'HH:mm' }}</pre>
```

Comment: Need to remove am/pm from up down timer. not from here.

Comment: Change `show-meridian` attribute. This line `<timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>` should look like this:  `<timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>`

Comment: Partially done. just need to show in 12 hour format in inside pre tag <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'HH:mm' }}</pre> currently it shows like 15:45

Comment: Replace `HH:mm` to `h:mm` or `hh:mm`, padded.